# Reading and displaying encrypted PDF-file in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, pdf, encryption, primefaces

according to [BalusC's homepage](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/05/pdf-handling.html) I implemented the function `downloadPDF()`, which reads a PDF-file from the filesystem and displays it in the browser. this function works as intended.

moreover I have a class `EncryptionService`, which lets me encrypt and/or decrypt a given file. this also works as intended.

unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to read a PDF-file, decrypt it and display it in the browser. it ends with the browser trying to load the file over and over without showing anything at all.

the code below shows my simple modifications of BalusC's PDF handler.

```
public void showDocument(String path, boolean decrypt) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        if(!decrypt)
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        else {
            // update MessageDigets, return Key
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, genKey(passphrase));

            input = new BufferedInputStream(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), cipher), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + path + "\"");

        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        output.flush();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: Specifically at what point does the looping occur? Does `showDocument` finish executing? What's sent back to the browser? Look in the network tab of your browser to see both the response code, headers and response body package

Comment: @kolossus, `showDocument` does finish properly. the network tab doesn't display anything when I load something in a new tab. it shows system.jsf (the current site) when trying to load in the same tab. after a few second this results in the error `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

Comment: So there you go: what you set as `Content-Length` != what came over the wire in reality.

Comment: Could you give me a hint what the value should be? I don't really understand what the content-length should be if the lenght of the file.

Comment: well for one thing, encryption is likely to bulk up the size of the file and decryption will reverse the effect. That being said, you generally don't want to reuse the same variable for both variants of the file: caching and general I/O unreliability might cause problems. So to experiment, use separate `File`s for the encrypted and decrypted forms of the pdf; don't reuse `file` for both

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, there really was a difference (by 5) in the length of the encrypted/decrypted file. thank you, I will accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's happening**

Like the console error says

> net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

That indicates that the actual size of the content returned in the response body does not match the size indicated in the `Content-Length` header of the response.

**Why it's happening**

The reason for the discrepancy is spread across 2 factors:

- Encryption usually increases the size of the ciphered content. The process of encryption requires obfuscation of the content by means of a cipher which usually means throwing in stuff that would make the content unusable otherwise. Decryption on the other hand will return the content to it's original size
- Browsers are prone to caching. If you serve different files enough times (using the same file name), your browser is likely to just decide that it's the same file *with the same content* and just serve a cached version of the file. In your case, you're declaring a reference to an encrypted file, accessing the file, decrypting it and then writing the decrypted content right back into the same file handle for the encrypted version.
- Disk-based I/O is not a 100% in step with RAM or the CPU. Writing to disk and reading from disk still  carries overhead in the form of RAM waiting for the Disk.

**To Fix**

- Generate a random/different filename for each of the files involved in your operation. That means a separate filename for the encrypted content and a separate one for the decrypted form
- As a corollary to the point above, open different output streams to different files, also using different `File` access variables.

**Related:**

- [Unexpected behavior with backing bean method and 'oncomplete' attribute of Primefaces dialog.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22057664/1530938)